# How to pass jQuery function among functions to be used as $

Tags: javascript, jquery

I read somewhere that best way to use jQuery in JavaScript is to make a self-invoking-anonymous-function an pass it jQuery like this:

```
( function ($) {
    ...
}) (jQuery);
```

This way, `$` can also be used for other things in other-functions (like MooTools)

But how do I pass `jQuery` to other functions safely?

For instance, this doesn't work:

```
( function ($) {
    i_too_can_use_jquery('simple_string')l
}) (jQuery);

function i_too_can_use_jquery (aString, $=jQuery) { // causes error :(
    ...                                       // Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
}
```

So, what's the right way to do this?

Comment: Why can't you just do `var $ = jQuery;`?

Comment: Hmmm ... good point! I'll use this for now. But why didn't my method work?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Please add this as an answer so I can accept it

Comment: consider using [jQuery.noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/): either `var $_ = jQuery.noConflict();` or in the scope of the other conflicting lib.

Comment: Keep in mind that Mootools detects jQuery and keeps free the `$`, you can also use Mootools `document.id()`  instead of `$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to add a parameter, as you are not editing anything:

```
function x()
{   var $ = jQuery;
    // do something
}
```

However, you might want to edit the `$` one day, and this might make it a bit more difficult.  In any case, you could define the other function inside the IIFE and make it global:

```
(function ($, global) {
    global.i_too_can_use_jquery = function (aString) {
        // do something
    };
    i_too_can_use_jquery('simple_string');
})(jQuery, window);
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider using [jQuery.noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/):

```
var $_ = jQuery.noConflict();
$('someId'); // MooTools
$_('#someId'); // jQuery
```

or:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
$('someId'); // MooTools
(function($){
    $('#someId'); //jQuery
}(jQuery);
```

Comment: `+1` Wow, I had no idea there's something like `jQuery.noConflict()`.

Answer (score 1):

Every code "module" that wants to use jQuery in this fashion should be wrapped in the (function($) { ... })(jQuery) prefix/suffix.

So in your example, I can either assume that i_too_can_use_jquery is a function that is only used by the first anonymous module:

```
( function ($) {
    i_too_can_use_jquery('simple_string')l

function i_too_can_use_jquery (aString) {
    ...                                      
}
}) (jQuery);
```

Or as a method that needs to be exported:

```
// first module
( function ($) {
    i_too_can_use_jquery('simple_string')l

}) (jQuery);

// second module
(function($) {
window.i_too_can_use_jquery = function(aString) {
    ...                                      
}
})(jQuery);
```

Either of these fix the syntax error you are seeing, but as you can see, the second one has some "module" overhead in terms of maintaining the scope of the function.

However, you have to consider if you actually *need* this self-invoking-anonymous function. Do you actually use other libraries that use the $ character? Do you plan on doing so in the future? Don't write it if you don't need it.

Comment: But wouldn't that mean `i_too_can_use_jquery` can't be accessed from there?

Comment: make it window.i_too_can_use_jquery = function

Comment: Whoops, you are absolutely right. I changed the code snippets and expanded on your comments a bit.

Comment: Yes I plan to use MooTools later. I think I'll use **Qantas 94 Heavy**'s answer in comments above, it looks clean and simple.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript does not support the optional argument form you are using:

```
function i_too_can_use_jquery (aString, $=jQuery) { /* the $=jQuery is invalid */
```

The right way to implement optional arguments is to check if defined:

```
function i_too_can_use_jquery (aString, $) { /* the $=jQuery is invalid */
    if(typeof $ === 'undefined') $ = jQuery;
```

Comment: Or `$ = $ || jQuery;` instead of the `if` statement

Comment: @Sourabh while it works in this case, I prefer the explicit check because of circumstances like `function f(a) { a = a || 3; ... }`, which will do the wrong thing for `f(0)`